# I’m stuck with the first part of this sentence (the use of not only ... but also)

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

which one is correct to use?

**you don’t** or **don’t you**

> Not only (**you don’t**)/ (**don’t you**) get paid, but also you put your online safety and privacy in danger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Not only (you don’t)*/ *(don’t you) get paid, but also you put your*
> *online safety and privacy in danger.*

"Not only" when fronted triggers subject-auxiliary inversion, so "don't you" is correct.

This kind of inversion occurs in declarative clauses only when certain types of element are put in front position. Negatives are one very obvious type of element that trigger subject-auxiliary inversion when fronted:

> *Never had I seen such chaos*.
>
> *At no stage were they in danger.*

"Only" is not negative, but it is semantically close to a negative, in that *Only John liked it*, for example, entails *No one other than John liked it*.

Comment: I would prefer _Not only do you not get paid..._, because it emphasises _not_ more clearly.